# Как подсчитать количество элементов по одному из полей объектов списка List?

Tags: java

Нужно подсчитать количество элементов списка, по одному из полей.
Допустим список имеет в себе такие объекты:

```
ObservableList<Ticket> filteredData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        filteredData.add(new Ticket ("1","2","true"));
        filteredData.add(new Ticket ("7","2","true"));
        filteredData.add(new Ticket ("2","3","true"));
        filteredData.add(new Ticket ("3","2","true"));
        filteredData.add(new Ticket ("4","1","true"));
        filteredData.add(new Ticket ("3","1","true"));
```

Нужно подсчитать сколько объектов в данном списке, у которых второе поле совпадает, объекты могут меняться, так как их поля могут иметь любое строковое значение, ввод происходит через графический интерфейс. Для этого списка по второму полю есть 3 совпадающих объекта с значением 2, 2 совпадающих объекта с значением 1.

Comment: если бы это был обычный список, я бы предложил либо группировку через стримы, либо просто пройтись по данным и в хешмапу сложить колво дубликатов. Но это ObservableList, я с таким не работал.

Comment: @tym32167 он от обычного почти не отличается, если не составит труда - расскажите как можно решить это для обычного списка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подсчёт количества значений в данном поле приведёт к мапе, где ключом будет строка, а значением -- количество.

Предположим, класс `Ticket` имеет геттер для второго поля `public String getField2()`, тогда можно получить мапу:

```java
Map<String, Integer> field2Counts = filteredData
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Ticket::getField2,
        Collectors.summingInt(t -> 1)
    ));
```

Аналогично без StreamAPI с использованием `Map::merge`:

```java
Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
for (Ticket t : filteredData) {
    counts.merge(t.getField2(), 1, Integer::sum);
}
```

Comment: Ваше решение подходит, но интересно можно ли реализовать это через TreeSet

Comment: Что значит через `TreeSet`?  В отсортированном сете всё равно придётся хранить пару "значение_второго_поля - частота", то есть понадобится класс-обёртка -- тот же `Map.Entry` :)

Answer (score 0):

Я бы написал такой метод:

```
public static <K, V> Map<V, Long> groupingBy(Iterable<K> itrb, Function<K, V> extracter) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(itrb.spliterator(), false)
            .map(extracter)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
}
```

Реализация максимально абстрактная, ее можно использовать с любыми коллекциями, содержащие любой контент.

Вызываем метод, передавая в нее коллекцию и поле, по которому хотим группировать данные.

```
Map<String, Long> groupingBy = groupingBy(filteredData, Ticket::getParam1);
```

В данном примере вызова filteredData-наша коллекция, а а Ticket::getParam1 - вызов геттера поля с условным именем param1, по которому мы хоти произвести расчет.